Python if 文について
プログラミングの初心者です。教本を参考に添付の「素数判定」プログラムを打ち込んでみました。
正しく動作したのですが、5行目の if (num % i) == 0: は、2から順に割って余りがあるか判定し、最終的に「入力した数字自身で割る (range(2, num)」ということになるのでしょうか。
ということは、素数もその数字自身で割れば「余り==0」となって、if文の「素数ではありません」が実行されてしまうのではないでしょうか？


range(2,num)
ってのは、2からnum-1 までですよ

え、そうなんですか！数の数え方は「0から」というのは知ったのですが、range(2,num)は、2からnum-1までなのですか。そういう仕様なのでしょうか？たとえばrange(2,5）とすると、2から5までですよね？変数を指定すると「変数-1」となる、ということでしょうか？

@kitc print(*range(2, 5)) を実行して出力結果を確認してみてください。

python range、でぐぐってみましょう。解説サイトがたくさん引っかかります。https://note.nkmk.me/python-range-usage/

@matropolisさま、@y_waiwaiさま、ありがとうございます。「2 3 4」と表示されました。rangeについて、ご紹介いただいた解説サイトにてきちんと学びます。ありがとうございます！

「range(start, stop)のように引数に整数を2つ指定すると、start ≦ i < stopの連番が生成される」のですね。おぼえました！ありがとうございます。

入力したnumをiで割った余りで、iは2から順にnumまでの数を繰り返すのだと思います。3のときは3%2=1になり素数として判定されます。

アドバイスありがとうございます。すみませんちょっと理解が追いつきませんでした。他の方のアドバイスによると、「range(start, stop)のように引数に整数を2つ指定すると、start ≦ i < stopの連番が生成される」のですね。

素数の「余り==0」は理解できましたか？for in文のような気がするけど…。

はい、ありがとうございました。
